# Return Cancel to sender VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

I have a custom tab control located inside an MDI parent form.  I have a close button located on the tab.  When the tab close button is clicked, the tab is removed and a corresponding MDI child form is removed for the MDI parent form.  On the MDI child form I check various conditions inside its FormClosing event.  If conditions are not met, the closing of the form is canceled by placing

```
e.Cancel = True
```

inside the FormClosing event.  This all works, however, when the form close is cancelled, my tab has been removed and I no longer have an corresponding tab for the MDI Child form.  How can I return Cancel from the FormClosing event of the MDI child form, back to the close event of the tab control button on the MDI parent form?

I should mention that the tab control is not the standard .net tab, it was built on top of the standard .net tab control to allow for a close button on the tab.  I did not write the original code for this custom tab control.

Below is the tab close code that exists in the class for the custom tab control 'TabControlEx'.

```
Public Event CloseButtonClick As CancelEventHandler
Protected Overridable Sub OnCloseButtonClick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    If Not DesignMode Then
        Dim btn As Button = DirectCast(sender, Button)
        Dim tp As TabPage = CloseButtonCollection(btn)
        Dim ee As New CancelEventArgs
        RaiseEvent CloseButtonClick(sender, ee)
        If Not ee.Cancel Then
            Me.TabPages.Remove(tp)
            RePositionCloseButtons()
            Me.SelectedIndex = Me.TabCount - 1
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

This is the code that I use on the tab control on the MDI parent form

```
Private Sub TabControl_CloseButtonClick(sender As Object, e As System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs) Handles TabControl.CloseButtonClick

    Dim i As Integer
    If TabControl.TabPages.Count > 0 Then
        For i = 0 To Me.MdiChildren.Length - 1
            If i = TabControl.SelectedIndex Then
                Me.MdiChildren(i).Close()
            End If
        Next
    End If

End Sub
```

This is the FormClosing code that exists on the MDI child form.  I have simplified it to show just this scenario

```
Private Sub frmMyMdiChildForm_FormClosing(sender As Object, e As FormClosingEventArgs) Handles MyBase.FormClosing

    If (MsgBox("Do you wan to contiue closing", vbYesNo) = vbNo) Then
        e.Cancel = True
        'This is where I need to send the cancel command back to the sender somehow
        Exit Sub
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Why instead of closing form, close button doesn't have validation from FormClosing event. Then nothing will get closed unless it's ok to. Otherwise you will have to close those tabs in close event.

Comment: This would work, but the calling code page is the master page, the MDI parent.  I would have lots of child pages and therefore lots of validation code in one code page, and the relevant code is not then easy to find for the child pages.

Comment: Why not create public function in parent that will have to get validated before closing will be ok. All child pages could access that. I'm afraid the only other way would be to rebuild all child forms(not sure, I never did much with forms) and that would take longer to program

Comment: Thanks for your advice, it gave me an idea which seems to work for me. I simply detect if child form is visible- as the last line of code on the tab close event, if true, the form has not closed and therefore I call cancel. This the cancels the tab close. Your approach would also work. Thanks